# How to manage multi javascript alert box in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have create a form in html and have validate form data in php using If condition when the data is not valid, the error/message is displayed in Javascript Alert box. Suppose this is the form:

```
<form method=post>

<table>

        <tr>
          <td> Username: </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="username"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> User Password: </td>
          <td> <input type="password" name="userpass"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> Registration ID: </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="std_id"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> Student's Full Name: </td>
          <td> <input type='text' name='std_name'/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> Father's Name: </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="fname"/> </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td> Date of Birth: </td>
          <td> <input type="date" name="dob"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td> Admission Date: </td>
          <td> <input type="date" name="adm_date"/> </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td> Mobile No: </td>
          <td> <input type="text" name="contact" id="text" style="width:160px;"  /> </td>
        </tr>

</table>

            <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Submit"/> 

</form>
```

& here is the php code where I have check the form data for validation:

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

    if (isset ($_POST['insert']))
    {   
    $valid = true;


    if( (empty($_POST['std_name'])) )
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Please Enter Student Name!') </script>";
        $valid = false;
    }

    $cellNo = $_POST['contact'];
    if (!is_numeric ($_POST['contact']) || (strlen($cellNo) != 11) )
    {
        echo "<script> alert ('Mobile Number is not valid') </script>";
        $valid = false;
    }


    $current_date = date('Y/m/d');
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    if( strtotime ($_POST['dob']) >= strtotime($current_date) || ($dob > date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 4) )) )
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Invalid date of birth') </script>";
        $valid = false;
    }       

    $adm_date = $_POST['adm_date'];
    if( $adm_date < date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 1)) )
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Admission/Registration Date is too old!') </script>";
        $valid = false;
    }



    if ($valid)
    {
              mysql_query("INSERT into ........values .......");

          echo "<script> alert('1 Record inserted!') </script>";
    }

}

?>
```

Now what my question is that if the user doesn't enter the name & enters an invalid DOB or registration date, it will show alert boxes displaying messages for three of them e.g:

in 1st alert box  ("Please Enter Student Name")

in 2nd alert box ("Invalid date of birth")

in 3rd alert box ("Admission/Registration Date is too old")

what I want is that when it popup the first alert box it must stop showing up the others so how is it possible in php. I am not familiar with jquery and Ajax. so please help

I hope you have got what I want to do.

Comment: `alert` is a HORRIBLE way to show validation errors to the user. Please don't do that!

Comment: try adding `return false;` after alert();

Comment: So how to do it through jquery? Can you plz tell me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Save the message in a variable

```
$message = null;

$current_date = date('Y/m/d');
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
if( strtotime ($_POST['dob']) >= strtotime($current_date) || ($dob > date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 4) )) )
{
    $message = "<script> alert('Invalid date of birth') </script>";
    $valid = false;
}       

$adm_date = $_POST['adm_date'];
if( $adm_date < date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 1)) )
{
    $message = "<script> alert('Admission/Registration Date is too old!') </script>";
    $valid = false;
}



if ($valid)
{
          mysql_query("INSERT into ........values .......");

      $message = "<script> alert('1 Record inserted!') </script>";
}

if ( $message ) {
    echo $message; // and alert will work here for the last message only..
}
```

Comment: @user3274862 what didnt work? is there any change from the last time?

Answer (score 0):

try using if else

```
if (isset ($_POST['insert']))
{   
    $valid = true;
    $cellNo = $_POST['contact'];
    $current_date = date('Y/m/d');
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $adm_date = $_POST['adm_date'];


    if( (empty($_POST['std_name'])) ){
        echo "<script> alert('Please Enter Student Name!') </script>";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif (!is_numeric ($_POST['contact']) || (strlen($cellNo) != 11) ){
        echo "<script> alert ('Mobile Number is not valid') </script>";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif( strtotime ($_POST['dob']) >= strtotime($current_date) || ($dob > date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 4) )) ){
        echo "<script> alert('Invalid date of birth') </script>";
        $valid = false;
    }else{ 
    if( $adm_date < date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 1)) ){
        echo "<script> alert('Admission/Registration Date is too old!') </script>";
        $valid = false;
        }
    }

    if ($valid){
              mysql_query("INSERT into ........values .......");

          echo "<script> alert('1 Record inserted!') </script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving different values for `$valid` and alert according to that

```
 if (isset ($_POST['insert']))
    {   
    $valid = 0;
     $cellNo = $_POST['contact'];
    $current_date = date('Y/m/d');
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];

    $adm_date = $_POST['adm_date'];
    if( (empty($_POST['std_name'])) )
    {
        $valid = 1;
    }
    else if (!is_numeric ($_POST['contact']) || (strlen($cellNo) != 11) )
    {
        $valid = 2;
    }
    else if( strtotime ($_POST['dob']) >= strtotime($current_date) || ($dob > date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 4) )) )
    {
        $valid = 3;
    }       
    else if( $adm_date < date("Y/m/d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') - 1)) )
    {
        $valid = 4;
    }


    if($valid == 1 )
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Please Enter Student Name!') </script>";
    } 
    else if($valid == 2 )
    {
        echo "<script> alert ('Mobile Number is not valid') </script>";
    } 
    else if($valid ==3  )
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Invalid date of birth') </script>";
    } 
    else if($valid == 4  )
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Admission/Registration Date is too old!') </script>";
    } 
    else if ($valid == 0 )
    {
              mysql_query("INSERT into ........values .......");

          echo "<script> alert('1 Record inserted!') </script>";
    }

}
```

But i advice you not do validation like this.Instead do validation using javascript or Jquery

**EDIT**

After jquery validation form automatically moves to php code part.So new php coding will look like

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
if (isset ($_POST['insert']))
{ 
   mysql_query("INSERT into ........values .......");

   echo "<script> alert('1 Record inserted!') </script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: So how to do it through jquery? Can you plz tell me in detail?

Comment: i can give you only sample of how to do. please check it here http://jsfiddle.net/xdckj/5/

Comment: while using jquery please add this line in head part of html `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Comment: if you have any further problem please post i will try to sort it out

Comment: Yes one question, when the condition remains true then where to use the INSERT query to insert the form data in table. I am talking about this one: `if ($valid)
    {
              mysql_query("INSERT into ........values .......");

          echo "<script> alert('1 Record inserted!') </script>";
    }`

Comment: You can use old php coding but without validation parts

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<?php
    function do_alert($msg) 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $msg . '"); </script>';
    }
?>
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>

<?php
    do_alert("Hello");
?>
</body>
</html>
```